# Replace ":" with "-" while also formatting mac address

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm currently using this to format an input text to have "-" after two characters and it replaces characters that are not "a-f" or "0-9" with "".

```js
var macAddress = document.getElementById("macInput");

function formatMAC(e) {
  var r = /([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})/i,
      str = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-f0-9]/ig, "");

  while (r.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(r, '$1' + '-' + '$2');
  }
  e.target.value = str.slice(0, 17);
};

macAddress.addEventListener("keyup", formatMAC, false);
```

I want it to also detect if the user writes ":" and replace it with "-", so it becomes impossible to write ":". Not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you try `str.replace(/:+/g, "-")` ? It replaces 1 or more `:` by `-`.

Comment: I believe using the `keydown` event instead of `keyup` here will provide a better UX (https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/keydown-is-the-only-keyboard-event-we-need/). Also, you may want to also add your function to the `paste` event :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. `.split().join()`

```
var macAddress = document.getElementById("macInput");

function formatMAC(e) {
  var r = /([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})/i,
      str = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-f0-9]/ig, "");

  while (r.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(r, '$1' + '-' + '$2');
  }
  e.target.value = str.slice(0, 17).split(':').join('');
};

macAddress.addEventListener("keyup", formatMAC, false);
```